# Windows - Enable write caching on this device

Tags: windows, sata

When this option is enabled on a SATA device, does it enable the disks on board write back cache (i.e 32mb) or does it enable the operating systems write back cache (i.e RAM)?

Or more specifically, when the option is not set, does it disable the disks write back cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It enables the on board write-back cache if it can be managed by the OS. Otherwise, if it doesn't have the function it could use software write back. If it's unset, it is disabled.

Note: It is a best practice not to enable write cache mode on a Domain Controller.

Comment: I would presume enabled means at least the os cache.

I just can't find a clear answer that unsetting it actually disables the on board cache. Not to mention a definitive answer on whether that setting would survive across ATA resets..

Comment: Usually, if it's the onboard cache, it will be greyed out in Windows because it has to be disabled by the BIOS. If you have the option, then you can either control the BIOS setting or it's software. I'll admit it's hard to tell which one unless you lookup the documentation for your server.

Comment: Fair. I give up :)